I am getting multiple errors while running a streaming model for audio. I am using insanely-fast-whisper along with the give model
Code is:
import torch
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers.utils import is_flash_attn_2_available

pipe = pipeline(
    "automatic-speech-recognition",
    model = "openai/whisper-large-v3",
    torch_dtype = torch.float16,
    device="cuda:0",
    model_kwargs = {'arrn_implementation':'flash_attention_2'} if is_flash_attn_2_available() else {"attn_implementation":"sdpa"}

)
import time
import numpy as np
def infer(audio_path):
  print(audio_path)
  start =  time.time()
  print("Loading audio")
  outputs = pipe(
      audio_path,
      chunk_length_s = 5,
      batch_size = 24,
      return_timestamps = True,
      generate_kwargs={"task": "translate"}
  )
  print("Done")
  end = time.time()
  print(end - start)
  return outputs
import gradio as gr
audio_input = gr.Audio(sources="microphone")
output_text = gr.Textbox()


demo = gr.Interface(
    fn = infer, 
    inputs = audio_input,
    outputs = output_text,
    live=True
)
demo.launch(debug=True, share=True)

anything wrong with the code? Tried multiple ways but couldn't get it. However if the audio file is give, the response is returned correctly. Thanks in advance
